# Can PowerPC64 ELF file have 32-bit pointers?

Tags: elf, powerpc

I've been given an ELF binary file which self describes as PowerPC 64-bit. The `e_entry` field of the ELF header points to the beginning of a section called `.opd`. According to this [specification](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/ELF/ppc64/PPC-elf64abi-1.9.html#ELF-HEAD), it is supposed to point to a function descriptor. The same [specification](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/ELF/ppc64/PPC-elf64abi-1.9.html#FUNC-DES) states that a function descriptor consists of three doublewords (64-bit words).

However, the binary in question (available [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/decompiler/feature-requests/11/attachment/21sample.elf)) appears to have only two 32-bit words for each function descriptor.

So the question is, why are there 32-bit pointers in this 64-bit binary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PS3 (cell) ABI used 64-bit registers but 32-bit pointers. Maybe this sample is from there.

P.S. section names `.sceStub.text` and `.rodata.sceResident` definitely point to Sony code (SCE= Sony Computer Entertainment)

Comment: Is there any (preferrably documented) way to tell that a file is a PS3 executable, as opposed to a "regular" PPC ELF file with 64-bit pointers? I see no clues in the standard ELF headers. Are there any other ways to determine this, apart from looking at those section names?

Comment: check `e_ident[EI_OSABI]`.